# В чем может быть ошибка в этом куске программы?

Tags: python

Текст куска программы:

```
    from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz

    estimator = forest.estimators_[1]
    export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', feature_names = ['AGE','LDL','HDL','TG','LPA','APOA','APOB','GLU','WAI','code_SEX','CHDR2W'],class_names = ['DIS5'])

    # Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)
    from subprocess import call
    call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])

    # Display in jupyter notebook
    from IPython.display import Image
    Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

Не могу понять, в чем может быть ошибка? 
Текст ошибки:

```
>     IndexError: list index out of range
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-810061e494ae> in <module>
      5 export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', 
      6                 feature_names = ['AGE','LDL','HDL','TG','LPA','APOA','APOB','GLU','WAI','code_SEX','CHDR2W'],
----> 7                 class_names = ['DIS5'])
      8 
      9 # Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in export_graphviz(decision_tree, out_file, max_depth, feature_names, class_names, label, filled, leaves_parallel, impurity, node_ids, proportion, rotate, rounded, special_characters, precision)
    457 
    458         # Now recurse the tree and add node & edge attributes
--> 459         recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0, criterion=decision_tree.criterion)
    460 
    461         # If required, draw leaf nodes at same depth as each other

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in recurse(tree, node_id, criterion, parent, depth)
    377             if left_child != _tree.TREE_LEAF:
    378                 recurse(tree, left_child, criterion=criterion, parent=node_id,
--> 379                         depth=depth + 1)
    380                 recurse(tree, right_child, criterion=criterion, parent=node_id,
    381                         depth=depth + 1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in recurse(tree, node_id, criterion, parent, depth)
    379                         depth=depth + 1)
    380                 recurse(tree, right_child, criterion=criterion, parent=node_id,
--> 381                         depth=depth + 1)
    382 
    383         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in recurse(tree, node_id, criterion, parent, depth)
    334             out_file.write('%d [label=%s'
    335                            % (node_id,
--> 336                               node_to_str(tree, node_id, criterion)))
    337 
    338             if filled:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\export.py in node_to_str(tree, node_id, criterion)
    299                 node_string += 'class = '
    300             if class_names is not True:
--> 301                 class_name = class_names[np.argmax(value)]
    302             else:
    303                 class_name = "y%s%s%s" % (characters[1],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Готово :) Спасибо, я тут просто новенький

Comment: а `estimator = forest.estimators_[1]` нормально отрабатывает ?

Comment: Да. Ввожу:
estimator = forest.estimators_[1]
print (estimator)

Вывод:
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=5,
            max_features=5, max_leaf_nodes=None, min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
            min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False, random_state=2135392491, splitter='best')

Comment: Вместо png файла формируется вордовский с текстом: digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="HDL <= 0.64\ngini = 0.038\nsamples = 4071\nvalue = [6330, 126]\nclass = DIS5"] ;
1 [label="HDL <= 0.575\ngini = 0.494\nsamples = 6\nvalue = [5, 4]\nclass = DIS5"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 5\nvalue = [5, 0]\nclass = DIS5"] ;
1 -> 2 ;

Comment: есть идеи как можно воспроизвести эту ошибку?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: те люди, которые захотят вам помочь должны иметь возможность вопроизвести эту ошибку... Откройте новый терминал Jupyter / iPython и попытайтесь воспроизвести эту ошибку используя исключительно ту часть информации / кода, которая есть в вопросе...

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Боюсь, что не получится это сделать, потому что алгоритм заточен под базу данных, которая стоит больших денег. А у вас нет идей, в чем может быть проблема? Хоть какие-то варианты?

Comment: В такой случае единственное что приходит на ум это гугл